# How can I make ESS to split window horizontally by default?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I always prefer horizontally splitting because the screen has more horizontal space.
In python-mode I can achieve this by setting

```
 (py-split-windows-on-execute-function (quote split-window-horizontally))
```

Is there something similar in ESS mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if ESS has anything mode-specific.  From the help pages, however, it looks like `split-window-preferred-function` defaults to `split-window-sensibly`, which in turn determines how to split a window based on `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold`.  Setting the former to `nil` forbids a horizontal split, and the latter to `nil` forbids a vertical split.  These settings would be global; you could put `(setq-local split-height-threshold nil)` in your `ess-mode-hook`.

*Edited/extended to reflect @qed's answer.*  You might consider packaging the local bindings in a function rather than in a lambda to give yourself the option of removing the function from the hook.

```
(defun forbid-vertical-split ()
  "Only permit horizontal window splits."
  (setq-local split-height-threshold nil)
  (setq-local split-width-threshold 0))

(require 'ess-site)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
          'forbid-vertical-split)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
(require 'ess-site)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (setq-local split-height-threshold nil)
            (setq-local split-width-threshold  0)
            ))
```

Kudos to Dan!

Comment: Great, glad it works!  I edited the earlier answer to reflect this, and included a suggestion to wrap it in a function rather than a lambda so you could remove it from the hook later if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

accepted answer did not work for me, but adding

```
(setq split-height-threshold 0)
```

to .emacs did